# doubling as a “door stop”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> With only a handful of commands, the SQL data statements look deceptively simple.
>   In my opinion, many of the available SQL books help to foster this notion by only
>   skimming the surface of what is possible with the language. However, if you are going
>   to work with SQL, it behooves you to understand fully the capabilities of the language
>   and how different features can be combined to produce powerful results. I feel that this
>   is the only book that provides detailed coverage of the SQL language without **the added
>   benefit of doubling as a “door stop”** (you know, those 1,250-page “complete references”
>   that tend to gather dust on people’s cubicle shelves).

What is exactly **doubling as a door stop** supposed to mean? Does it mean that you are going to use that big reference book, if you purchased one instead of this one that you're reading, as a second door stop because the book is useless and because your door stop is not good enough to hold your door ajar?

Comment: So your real question is "what does 'doubling as' mean?" ?

Comment: If you do get it, and if you do understand what the author means (and he thankfully even explains it right there in the very same sentence), then what is the question? What *is* your understanding, and what is still missing? Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be effective, a door stop has to be heavy enough to stop the door from moving.

The author is touting his book as being the only one that offers complete SQL information in a format that is smaller/has less total pages. This implies the information density is greater, and thus you will waste less time when you read it.

Based on your edit:

When something "doubles as" something else, it serves its original function, as well as some 2nd function. It does double the number of jobs. [It's a very commonly used idiom](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22double+as%22).

Comment: Thanks. Double as something or someone is going to do it for me. I looked it up. Sometimes is hard to tell when it is an idiom and when it is just regular words when a verb with a preposition are involved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ODE:

> a heavy or bulky object, especially a thick book: his sixth novel is a thumping 400-page doorstop.

And here the author is trying to say that the book is not very thick as some other guides.